# How do I create a function that replaces a substring given its start and end indexes with another string

Tags: clojure

I have a string "Hello" and I want to replace the characters between the two indexes with another string, say "Foo". E.g.

```
(defn new-replace [orig-str start-index end-index new-string] ...)

(= "Foollo" (new-replace "Hello" 0 2 "Foo")) => true
(= "Foolo" (new-replace "Hello" 0 3 "Foo")) => true
```

Any suggestions? Cheers

Comment: I've used subs to create two strings excluding the string I want to remove and concatenated with the new-string in the centre. Doesn't seem so elegant, maybe there's a more elegant, clojure idiomatic way? @cfrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
(defn new-replace [orig-str start-index end-index new-string]
   (str (apply str (take start-index orig-str))
        new-string
        (apply str (drop end-index orig-str))))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stringbuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) already provieds a *replace* function:

```
(defn new-replace [orig-str start-index end-index new-string]                                                                                                                                                      
  (str (.replace (StringBuffer. orig-str) start-index end-index new-string)))
```

Comment: Good answer if you use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` …